# Take images without closing camera in Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to develop camera functionality for my app where I have to capture 10 images. The camera should not close, rather it should continuously take pictures while I hold the shutter button. I am using intent for opening the camera, but after taking one image the camera is stopping. How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: For this kind functionality you need to implement custom camera

Comment: can you just clearyfy how to make

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement burst mode?

Comment: no if i click image then i want 1 image but camera still open then if i click again i want second image

Comment: like android inbuild camera after tacking image you can tack onother image without closing camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write your own camera code, using `android.hardware.Camera` and/or the `android.hardware.camera2.*` classes. There is no `Intent` structure that camera app developers are required to support that handles your use case.